# while executing queries on multithreading it says connection pool exhausted

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, psycopg2

I am executing 3 queries for a single table and I am running it on 5 tables, so I am using threading per table, when I tried to execute the program, it always says below error message:

I have tried with the below code:

```
def get_cursor()
pool = ThreadedConnectionPool(
            minconn=3,
            maxconn=5,
            dbname=databaseb_name,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            host=host,
            port=port
        )
conn = pool.getcon()
cursor = conn.cursor()
return cursor
```

but it couldn't help.

please suggest.

Comment: Sorry, what was your error message?

Comment: @Cyberwiz, it is saying that connection pool exhausted, when I provide more connection it becomes slow.